# Converting layered SVG vector graphic into layered EPS vector graphic

Tags: php, vector, svg, vector-graphics, eps

Is it possible to convert a layered vector .SVG file into a layered .EPS file?

I'm trying to programmatically compile a series of .SVG's into one large .SVG, then import it into Photoshop so that can be easily opened by Adobe Illustrator.

Could really use any advice/guidance! There doesn't appear to be any documentation on how Adobe's layered .EPS files are put together.

Comment: What do you mean by a "layered SVG file"? There are no layers in SVG, there are groups that some drawing tools use as a way to represent layers.

Comment: Illustrator opens SVGs directly - why the need to go via EPS & Photoshop?

Answer (score 5):

Adobe Illustrator should be able to open the SVG directly, without the need to convert it to EPS.

You can use [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) to convert an SVG file to EPS:

```
inkscape -E file.eps file.svg
```

If you're trying to do that in PHP, you can just [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) the command.

But there are no native "layers" in SVG, so you'll just get a plain EPS file.

If you really need to convert some groups into layers, then you'll have to write your own converter which knows that some groups should be layers.

Comment: yea that's one possibility but I was looking for some Apache or php plugin.

Comment: Plugin for converting SVG to EPS, or a plugin that knows how to do that preserving layers?

Comment: In the event you want to do it in PHP would you be opposed to `exec('inkscape -E file.eps file.svg')`? This would still leverage Inkscape but allow you to make the call from within PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the SVG files directly with Illustrator and drag and drop each image into photoshop to create a multi-layered PSD.